# Loop stops prematurely

Tags: powershell

I am writing an application that looks through a directory tree and reports if a folder is inactive based on last write time and read only attribute.

However my loop stops after like 7 iterations even though there are thousands of folders.

My code looks like:

```
function FolderInactive{
    Param([string]$Path)
    $date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
    $anyReadOnly = $false
    Get-ChildItem $Path -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        if($_.LastWriteTime -ge $date){
            $false
            continue

        }
        if($_.IsReadOnly -eq $false){
            $anyReadOnly = $true
        }
    }
    $anyReadOnly
}

Get-ChildItem "some drive" -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.FullName
    FolderInactive($_.FullName)

}
```

If I comment out the `FolderInactive` function call in the Foreach loop it prints all the folders, but with the function call it stops after a few iterations. What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `continue` with the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet. `Foreach-Object` is a cmdlet, **not a loop**. You instead want to use the loop:

```
function FolderInactive{
    Param([string]$Path)
    $date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
    $anyReadOnly = $false
    $items = Get-ChildItem $Path -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    foreach($item in $items)
    {
        if($item.LastWriteTime -ge $date){
            $false
            continue

        }
        if($item.IsReadOnly -eq $false){
            $anyReadOnly = $true
        }
    }
    $anyReadOnly
}
```

This also can be simplified:

```
function FolderInactive
{
    Param([string]$Path)
    $date = (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)
    $null -ne (Get-ChildItem $Path -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Where {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $date -and $_.IsReadOnly})   
}
```